# Why does containsKey() return false even though the UUID is in the HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, bukkit

Hi i'm making a small minecraft server for me and some friends and I have not worked with java for a while, im using spigot 1.14.1 btw.
sadly my containsKey() returns false even though I ran the first command and know that my UUID is in the HashMap.
If anyone could explain it would be great, if possible a altered version of my code besides the explanation :) 
Thanks alot in advanced.

I have tried making my own contains boolean didnt work sadly

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import me.melorn.com.pineapplegang.mc.chatutility.Prefix;
import me.melorn.com.pineapplegang.mc.programutility.HashMapUtility;

public class TempYannick implements CommandExecutor{

    private static Location joejoespawn;

    private HashMap<UUID, Location> OLDLOCATIONS = new HashMap<UUID, Location>();

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String args[]) {
        if(sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("joejoe")) {
                this.OLDLOCATIONS.put(player.getUniqueId(), player.getLocation());
                player.sendMessage(Prefix.getPineappleCore() + Prefix.getChatPrefix() + Prefix.getChatColor() + " You have ben teleported to " + Prefix.getPlayerNameColor() + "JoeJoe's" + Prefix.getChatColor() + " Creative Universe");
            }else if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("joejoeback")) {
                if(this.OLDLOCATIONS.containsKey(player.getUniqueId())) {
                    this.OLDLOCATIONS.remove(player.getUniqueId());
                    player.sendMessage(Prefix.getPineappleCore() + Prefix.getChatPrefix() + Prefix.getChatColor() + " You teleported back to your old location away from " + Prefix.getPlayerNameColor() + "JoeJoe's " + Prefix.getChatColor() + " Creative Universe");
                }else {
                    player.sendMessage(Prefix.getPineappleCore() + Prefix.getChatPrefix() + Prefix.getChatColor() + " You cant teleport back from " + Prefix.getPlayerNameColor() + "JoeJoe's" + Prefix.getChatColor() + " Creative Universe if you have not ben there!");
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I expect that the containsKey() would return true so that the "You teleported back to your old location"message would be sent to the player.

Comment: Are you sure the same `TempYannick ` instance is used in both calls to `onCommand`? If not, the `Map` will be empty in the second call.

Comment: lol thanks I feel so stupid now. thats it I used new TempYannick for both the commands.

Comment: I just wanted to add that you could use a `private static HashMap<...` instead like you did with the `private static Location joejoespawn`